# Newton integration without integration

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ho.history-overview

Consider a function f continuous on a compact interval.

Approximate it by a sequence of polygonal functions (you can).

Then consider a sequence of primitives of the polygonal functions (you can).

At last consider the limit of the latter sequence (you can).

Now you have found a primitive of f (you know) *without integration*.

This is the content of the first part of a not very known note by Lebesgue [*Remarques sur la définition de l'intégrale*](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k4862594/f234.image.langEN), Bull.Sci.Math. 29 (1905) 272-275 (see [pdf](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.1412v1.pdf) for an exposition in English).

I doubt that such a thing was shown for the first time in 1905.

Lebesgue's good faith is beyond discussion of course.

Do you know something about ?

Comment: The trapezoid rule?

Comment: @Noah Stein yes!

Comment: This is basically how I think about the fundamental theorem...


Comment: To avoid misunderstanding: quite a long time several authors call antidifferentiation **Newton integration**. This allowed me the pun of the title. The second integration means Cauchy-Riemann integration of course.

Comment: Anyhow the procedure shows the existence of a primitive **directly** avoiding the typical tour (i) develop the Riemann integral (ii) prove that continuous functions are Riemann integrable (iii) prove the fundamental theorem of the calculus for the Riemann integral.  
Obviously one can use step functions to approximate f.

Comment: _you can_  , _you know_  mean statements allowed by the theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. What does this procedure have to do with Newton? Just curious.
2. If you approximate with "polygonal" (=piecewise linear) functions in the most natural way,
   that is take points $(x_k,f(x_k))$ and connect them with straight line segments, what you obtain
   is the "trapezoid rule" for approximate evaluation of integrals.
3. Of course, the trapezoid rule is "a theorem of Adam"; already Gauss knew much more sophisticated rules.
4. Convergence of the procedure with any continuous function and any (reasonable) choice of $x_k$
   is a trivial exercise for modern students, and it was probably in 1905.
   I looked at the paper, and it seems to me that in it, Lebesgue only proposes a simple way
   to TEACH the integral. There is nothing really new in this paper.

Comment: for Newton see R.Henstock - Lectures on the theory of integration page 29 but the possible quotations are many

Comment: for me the fact that a uniformly convergent sequence of derivatives represents a derivative is not Adam's

Comment: Antonio, In this procedure you only need that integrals of uniformly
convergent functions are convergent.

Comment: In the end I agree with you: it's the meaning of my question. But Medvedev ... ?

Comment: What about Medvedev? Does he say anything about this paper of Lebesgue?

Comment: I quote F.A.Medvedev from *Scenes from the History of Real Functions* page 183 "... A noncircular proof of the existence of a primitive for a continuous function turned out to be very difficult, and was achieved only at the beginning of the twentieth century by Lebesgue [quotation of the note]...".

Comment: did you read pdf above ? Coppin says: this beautiful proof of his is not known in the English speaking world.

Comment: Medvedev goes back to the subject in The Work of Henri Lebesgue in the Theory of Functions of a Real Variable (Russian Math. Surveys 30:4, 179-191).
And so Angus E.Taylor reviewing the Scenes (Bull.AMS 28:2 360-367).
Lebesgue himself speaks of it in his Lecons sur L'integration (1904 edition, pag. 87; 1928 edition, pag. 95).

Comment: also, from page 66 of the Scenes, Medvedev: ... It was only in 1905 that Lebesgue [quotation of the note] succeeded in proving the existence of a primitive for every continuous function without resorting to the definition of an integral as a limit of sums ...

Comment: Interesting. Unfortunately I do not have Medvedev's book, and on the 
Internet I found it for $229, and my interest 8is not sufficient to pay this amount to satisfy it:-(

Comment: Medvedev is an historian, not a real mathematician, so it is possible that he confused something. The book on the history of integral that
I have (by I. Pesin, who is a mathematician) does not mention this paper
of Lebesgue. But of course I can say nothing definite without seeing Medvedev's book.